# Is $Q(b)=a^Hb+b^Ha$ ,where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times1},b^Hb\leq\epsilon^2$convex or concave?

Tags: convex-optimization

We assume that $a,b \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times1},b^Hb\leq\epsilon^2$. Is the function 
$Q(b)=a^Hb+b^Ha$  convex,concave?  In other words, which of the following problems is 
feasible?

$\min\ \  a^Hb+b^Ha  \\  s.t.\ \ \ b^Hb\leq\epsilon^2$

or

$\max\ \  a^Hb+b^Ha  \\  s.t.\ \ \  b^Hb\leq\epsilon^2$

Comment: Do I overlook something. Your function is real-linear, hence convex and concave, as
$$ Q((1-\lambda)b_1 + \lambda b_2) = (1-\lambda)Q(b_1) + \lambda Q(b_2)$$ for $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, martini. I am just a beginner.